# Oracle Partition By to get data from multiple groups

Tags: oracle, group-by, window-functions, rank

I have a table where the data looks like below

```
ID  Timestamp   Value  
1   2/2/2015 12:05  1  
2   2/2/2015 12:05  2  
3   2/2/2015 12:05  2  
1   2/2/2015 12:10  1  
2   2/2/2015 12:10  2  
3   2/2/2015 12:10  2  
1   2/2/2015 12:15  null  
2   2/2/2015 12:15  3  
3   2/2/2015 12:15  2  
1   2/2/2015 12:20  null
2   2/2/2015 12:20  1
3   2/2/2015 12:20  3
1   2/2/2015 12:25  null
2   2/2/2015 12:25  10
3   2/2/2015 12:25  9
1   2/2/2015 12:30  1
2   2/2/2015 12:30  2
3   2/2/2015 12:30  1
1   2/2/2015 12:35  null
2   2/2/2015 12:35  2
3   2/2/2015 12:35  1
1   2/2/2015 12:40  null
2   2/2/2015 12:40  2
3   2/2/2015 12:40  2
```

I want to group the values on the basis of null and filter out the min and max time that the null appeared in a contiguous time block. Below is the desired output. I have tried using the partition by clause but not getting the desired result

```
1   2/2/2015 12:15  2/2/2015 12:25  null
1   2/2/2015 12:35  2/2/2015 12:40  null
```

Comment: *contiguous time block* Not at clear what you mean by that. Can you please explain your desired output. How are those rows in your example output derived, explain the rules.

Comment: If you see the samples are collected every 5 minutes i.e. ID 1,2,3 have a value every 5 minutes. This value can be null or any numeric number. What I want to do is find out blocks of time when null appeared in subsequent sample e.g. ID 1 null appeared at 12:15, 12:20 and 12:25 so the output row should have "start time " when null started appearing and "end time" till null was appearing .. ie. till the value changes and again similarly find other such blocks

Comment: I'm using the query below -- but the problem is that it's giving me the minmum and maximum time for "null" value from the entire dataset not from  subgroups like I want

Comment: select id, Min_SAMPLETIME,MAX_SAMPLETIME, samplevalue
From (
SELECT S_DATA.ID as table_id,S_DATA.SAMPLETIME as sampletime,
MIN(S_DATA.SAMPLETIME)  over (partition by S_DATA.SAMPLEVALUE, S_DATA.ID) AS Min_SAMPLETIME,MAX(S_DATA.SAMPLETIME) over (partition by S_DATA.SAMPLEVALUE, S_DATA.ID) AS Max_SAMPLETIME, S_DATA.SAMPLEVALUE as samplevalue from SB.S_DATA S_DATA where (sampletime = Min_SAMPLETIME or sampletime = Max_SAMPLETIME) and samplevalue is null

Answer (score 0):

You can try this;

This is take a minute

```
SELECT 
 EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM TO_TIMESTAMP('03/12/14 11:15:00','DD/MM/YY HH24:MI:SS')) 
FROM DUAL
```

Probably your script will be;

```
SELECT id,
       min(EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM TO_TIMESTAMP(your_timestamp_cloumn))),
       value
  from table_name
 where value is null
 group by id,value
UNION
SELECT id,
       max(EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM TO_TIMESTAMP(your_timestamp_cloumn))),
       value
  from table_name
 where value is null
  group by id,value
```

Edit:

If your 'Timestamp' coulmn's format is timestamp you can try this script;

```
SELECT id,
       min(to_char(your_timestamp_cloumn,'MI')),
       value
  from onur_deneme
 where value is null
 group by id,value
UNION
SELECT id,
       max(to_char(your_timestamp_cloumn,'MI')),
       value
  from onur_deneme
 where value is null
  group by id,value
```

Comment: Hi Onur, I added group by clause to the query but didn't get desired output

Comment: I think, you do not need group by query for your example output because where condition filter only null values. Do not you need it ?

Comment: Sorry, not an expert on this but I guess Min function will not work without using group by

Comment: I'm using the query below -- but the problem is that it's giving me the minmum and maximum time for "null" value from the entire dataset not from subgroups like I want

select id, Min_ST,MAX_ST, samplevalue From ( SELECT S_DATA.ID as table_id,S_DATA.SAMPLETIME as sampletime, MIN(S_DATA.SAMPLETIME) over (partition by S_DATA.SAMPLEVALUE, S_DATA.ID) AS Min_ST,MAX(S_DATA.SAMPLETIME) over (partition by S_DATA.SAMPLEVALUE, S_DATA.ID) AS Max_ST, S_DATA.SAMPLEVALUE as samplevalue from SB.S_DATA S_DATA where (sampletime = Min_ST or sampletime = Max_ST) and samplevalue is null

Comment: Hi Onur, tried the code. I get the minimum value of timestamp with the id but the maxvalue doesn't come.

Comment: I edit my code . You can try. I hope it will be useful for you